# I cracked my door at the door handle plate. What can I use to fix and reattach the door handle?

Tags: doors, doorknob

I cracked my door at the door handle plate. What can I use to fix and reattach the door handle?

[image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: The handle plate is a 1.5x1.5 inch. The screws that where holding it are half inch. But the door is 2inch thick and Sean’s to be solid wood. I was thinking some JB wood epoxy. Not sure if I need to to remove the door and lay it flat or just epoxy while it standing. 
Thank you all for your advise it’s greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most epoxies want to be clamped or weighted down in some fashion.  You want to "clean out" the hole so the wood can lay flat in the repair area. Epoxy up any voids in the area. Epoxy up a few toothpicks and stick them in the screw holes so you have some new wood when re attaching the handle.

Comment: @Holottalumps, please put all your information in your question post. It doesn't belong down here in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the handle and get a good wood glue and brush it in all the cracks. Clamp it until the glue dries (varies with the type of glue). If you can't clamp it, I'd suggest removing the door, laying it flat and weight down a piece of wood over the glues area until the glue dries. Then re attach the handle.

If using epoxy, most epoxies want to be clamped or weighted down in some fashion. You want to "clean out" the hole so the wood can lay flat in the repair area. Epoxy up any voids in the area. Epoxy up a few toothpicks and stick them in the screw holes so you have some new wood when re attaching the handle.

Comment: you can easily clamp the door ... pass a bolt through the door handle hole ... put a large washer on each side of the door ... tighten using a nut on the bolt ... if you can't get really big washers, then drill a hole through a piece of wood

Comment: @jsotola  Great idea.

Comment: If you put a wood piece over the glued area to clamp make sure you put a piece of plastic bag, plastic wrap between the wood and door to avoid gluing the wood piece to the door. You can also place strips of plastic packing tape on the wood piece.

Comment: When you reattach the handle, using longer and thicker screws may help avoid a repeat of this failure.